# ASP.net page life cycle

Tags: asp.net

I am having an ASP.net page in my page i am having this as my code behind files.
on first access the page the page preinit, init, load methods are called. on postbacks
the preinit, init, load methods are called.

My question is LoadViewstate and control state events (Overridden methods) are not firing after postbacks also

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{

    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

}

protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadControlState(savedState);
}
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //  lblName.Text = ViewState["Test"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This method is used primarily by the
>   .NET Framework infrastructure and is
>   not intended to be used directly from
>   your code. However, control developers
>   can override this method to specify
>   how a custom server control restores
>   its view state. For more information,
>   see ASP.NET State Management Overview.
>
> The LoadViewState method restores the
>   view-state information that was saved
>   during a previous SaveViewState
>   request. The WebControl class
>   overrides the base LoadViewState
>   method to handle the ViewState, Style,
>   and Attributes properties.

Also note

> Control State Sometimes you need to
>   store control-state data in order for
>   a control to work properly. For
>   example, if you have written a custom
>   control that has different tabs that
>   show different information, in order
>   for that control to work as expected,
>   the control needs to know which tab is
>   selected between round trips. The
>   ViewState property can be used for
>   this purpose, **but view state can be
>   turned off at a page level by
>   developers, effectively breaking your
>   control.** To solve this, the ASP.NET
>   page framework exposes a feature in
>   ASP.NET called control state.
>
> The ControlState property allows you
>   to persist property information that
>   is specific to a control and cannot be
>   turned off like the ViewState
>   property.

[Asp.Net StateManagement link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

If your control is a customer server control take a look at

[iStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.istatemanager(VS.80).aspx)

And for the complete overview of viewstate - had to search my bookmarks try

[Truly understanding viewstate](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/truly-understanding-viewstate.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET optimizes this call, and calls the LoadViewState only if there is any custom data written to the view state.

If you set something to the view state in the first call (e.g. ViewState["foo"] = 42;), the LoadViewState will be called in the next (and subsequent) callbacks.